# Punctuation in UIText field causing wrong behaviour when checking intValue

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

If an entered value is under 200 in a UIText field, an alert is generated.

If the user adds   `>` in the field to signify its greater than 200, the alert is still fired.  Obviously I dont want this so I need some way of ignoring this punctuation or even better all punctuation

Defaulting to numeric values only is not an option

```
if  ([_myTextBox.text intValue]< 200){

   //alert is fired
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that whenever a string doesn't start from a valid decimal number, `intValue` returns 0. The correct way is to use number formatters:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSNumber *value = [formatter numberFromString:_myTextBox.text];
// if _myTextBox.text is not a valid number, value will be nil
if (number && ([number intValue] < 200) {
    // Place your code here
}
```

Comment: Ah thats it! Thanks for that and plus one for the explanation for why it was happening